# How to remove field@type while exporting from Azure storage explorer

Tags: azure, export, storage, azure-storage, export-to-csv

I am trying to export selected fields from Azure storage table, it creates an export as .csv.

But there is one column against each field column, exists in exported CSV file, as Field@type.

Can it be stopped being generated.

[image: Export snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your copy of Storage Explorer to version `v1.13.0`. As per the release notes mentioned [`here`](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases), this should be fixed.

Here's the link to the Github issue regarding this: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/2104

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answer Gaurav, however, I found a settings in "Azure Storage Explorer"

Under "Transfers" left column, if the checkbox "Export Type Annotations" is cleared, which is below head "Table Import/Export", the Field@type column will not come in export, see screen shot below
[image]